# Handling XmlSerializer errors

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have xml file with such structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Suite xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Name>WebGuiAutomation_Smoke_5</Name>
<Tests>

    <Test xsi:type="InitializeBrowser">      
        <TestName>Initialize browser</TestName>
        <BrowserType>Chrome</BrowserType>     
    </Test>

    <Test xsi:type="Connection">
        <TestName>General - Connection</TestName>
        <Machine>Machine</Machine>
        <Port>1234</Port>
        <UserName>User</UserName>
        <Password>Password</Password>
    </Test>     
</Tests>
```

And, some inherited types from Test (for example, **Connection**) is removed from the assembly. XmlSerialzer throws exception, that he couldn't find a type named **Connection**. I want to handle this errors, print information into console and ignore this block in the xml. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but I stumbled upon it a few days ago: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58etw60.aspx. `Deserialize` can be used with a `XmlDeserializationEvents` object. On this one you can listen to certain events that might be generated in your case (and possibly override or ignore them).

Comment: I've already tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work in this situation.